# Cutting the hair or nails according to islam

Tags: sunnah

Is there any particular days that one can not cut his or her hair or nails?

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no Authentic sources which prohibit the cutting of nails on certain times or days.

You may wish to see this for further information in regards to the cutting of nails:  [IslamQA(Arabic)](http://www.islam-qa.com/ar/118891)